# Create column "after" in Powerbi (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following information and I want to create the column "Later" From isProm : is the next day have the same value or no?

```
Date         isProm  Later
2018-06-06   1       1
2018-06-13   1       1
2018-08-20   1       1
2018-09-12   1       0
2018-09-12   0       0
```

Could you help me to do that with day please?

Thank you very much,

Ana

Answer (score 0):

Create your new **Custom Column** with this below code-

**Option 1:**

```
later = 

var current_row_isporm = your_table_name[isProm]
var current_row_date = your_table_name[Date]
var next_date =
CALCULATE(
    MIN(your_table_name[Date]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] > current_row_date
    )
)

var nex_date_isporm = 
CALCULATE(
    MIN(your_table_name[isProm]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] = next_date
    )
)

RETURN IF(current_row_isporm = nex_date_isporm,1,0)
```

**Option 2:** You can also use this below code for same output-

```
later = 

var current_row_isporm = your_table_name[isProm]
var current_row_date = your_table_name[Date]
var next_date_isporm =
CALCULATE(
    MINX(
        TOPN(
            1,
            FILTER(
                ALL(your_table_name),
                your_table_name[Date] > current_row_date
            ),
            your_table_name[Date].[Date],ASC
        ),
        your_table_name[isProm]
    )    
)

RETURN IF(current_row_isporm = next_date_isporm,1,0)
```

Here is the output. I have slightly different output because of date format in my laptop.

[image]

Comment: Actually I deed a mistake
I will change the table

Comment: HI @T.mum, Hope this will work for you. Please let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: i have a dimension with product so I think it's not ok :(

Comment: You have a dimension with product, where did you mentioned that. You need to explain everything. Half explanation will return "it's not ok", expected ;)